# How to get CLLocationManager's current coordinate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have a UIViewController where I want to display a map centered on current position.

AppDelegate's **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    return YES;
}
```

My **UIViewController.m** class looks like this:

```
@interface GMapViewController ()<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *currentLocation;

@end

@implementation GMapViewController

#pragma mark - Lifecycle methods

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.currentLocation = [CLLocation new];

    [[[AppDelegate appDelegate] locationManager] setDelegate:self];

    MKCoordinateRegion visibleRegion;
    visibleRegion.center = self.currentLocation.coordinate;
    visibleRegion.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(200, 200);

    [self.mapView setRegion:visibleRegion animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate's methods

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
    self.currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
}
```

The thing is the CLLocationManager's **didUpdateLocations** delegate method is called too late as the **currentLocation** property has no value when the **viewDidLoad** is called.

How can I get the current coordinate before **viewDidLoad** being called ?

Comment: Why don't you just import CoreLocation in your view controller?

Comment: CoreLocation has been imported in AppDelegate

Comment: Most likely `viewDidLoad` in `GMapViewController` is called sooner than `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`. Initialize `locationManager` lazily and move `startUpdatingLocation` to `viewDidLoad` after setting the delegate.

Comment: @vadian, the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called earlier than viewDidLoad

Comment: Nevertheless call `startUpdatingLocation` after setting the delegate.

Comment: @vadian, I have moved the call of startUpdatingLocation after setting the delegate , no better results

Comment: *"How can I get the current coordinate before viewDidLoad being called"* - you can't and you shouldn't try. Update the map's region when `didUpdateLocations` is called. Show something reasonable until that happens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh your map view once the location has been updated; this will take some time.

You also have a potential race condition, because you call `startUpdatingLocation` in your AppDelegate, but the view controller isn't set as the delegate until `viewDidLoad`.  The delegate will almost certainly be set before the location is updated, but you can't guarantee this.

I would suggest that you move everything into your view controller and if you only want to update the map once, use `requestLocation`:

```
@interface GMapViewController ()<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *currentLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation GMapViewController

#pragma mark - Lifecycle methods

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.currentLocation = nil;

        if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
            [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        } else {
            [self.locationManager requestLocation];
}

-(void) setMapTo:(CLLocation *)location {
      MKCoordinateRegion visibleRegion;
      visibleRegion.center =location.coordinate;
      visibleRegion.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(200, 200);

     [self.mapView setRegion:visibleRegion animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate's methods

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [self setMapTo:currentLocation];
    });
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status != kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted && status != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        [manager requestLocation];
    }
}
```

If you just want the map to track the user's location continually then you can simply set the map view's `userTrackingMode` property to `MKUserTrackingModeFollow`